# IOS development, using UITabBarController and UIImagePickerController, How to go from one tab to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I can't seem to find an answer for this, or maybe can't understand the things people wrote over the web...

I have a UITabBar with 3 tubs.

One of the tabs is a UIImagePickerController. This TabBar Item is connected to a view controller that i set also as the delegate for the Image picker (camera).

I want that then someone take a photo or press cancel, The first TabBar item will be choosen (don't want to stay in the TabBar that holds the camera).

My question is, How do I "talk" with the TabBar controller from a view controller that is in one of the TabBar items?

my code in the TakePhotoViewController.m file that is in the 3rd TabBer item and i want to go the first item.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
    self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];  
}
```

and the delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UIImagePicker delegate methods

//saving the image that was taken
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    // Save image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

    [picker release];
}

//alerting the user if the images was saved or not
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    UIAlertView *alert;

    // Unable to save the image  
    if (error)
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                       message:@"Unable to save image to Photo Album." 
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    else // All is well
        alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Success" 
                                       message:@"Image saved to Photo Album." 
                                      delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}

//if user is cancelling the camera
-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
}
```

Thank you very much,
Erez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

You can pass your desired tab index value instead of 1.

Comment: Thank you, so again I came out stupid.... But i don't understand how some self.tabBarController works??? It is not my property. Is it because i am inside an UITabBarController or what? Thank you :-)

Comment: Its like accessing the navigationController in subsequent views other than root view even you haven't declared a property for navigationController there. You can access the tabBarController from a viewController which is actually inside that tabBarController.